# upgrading ubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10 unable install some update for upgrade

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, openvpn

I have tried these commands to upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt upgrade fix-missing 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

While this `sudo do-release-upgrade` the following is output

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

While running `sudo apt upgrade fix-missing`  it shows this error
or doing upgrade through gui software updater suggested for only partial update still these packages are not updated
[image: could not download the upgrade]

Comment: This looks like a local network issue. Are you behind a proxy or other network infrastructure which blocks certain sites?

Comment: yes always face such errors while update even normal installing some packages should i used my personal mobile network to upgrade